# Facebook is not picking my site_name property when shared

Tags: facebook, meta

When i share post Facebook is not picking meta property site_name instead i get my website's URL when i debug my site name is there?

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:description" content="mySite">
<meta property="og:url" content="mySite">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="mySite">
```

Comment: I have the same issue... anyone have a clue? It appears fine on metatags.io but site_name isn't displayed on Facebook or Whatsapp.